# What means this code?

Tags: assembly, c++

```
cseg01:00020DB8                 mov     eax, offset screen_with_height
cseg01:00045704                 mov     dword ptr [eax+0Ah], 0
cseg01:0004570B                 call    sub_466F8 ; call some proc

dseg05:000C2090 screen_with_height dd 0C80140h ;320 by 200 pixels 0x140 by 0xC8
```

This is C++ WATCOM compiler.

Please explain what means this code, why would be need this code?

I dont understatnd this line:

```
mov     dword ptr [eax+0Ah], 0
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The byte at that address is zeroed out  the why part is not answerable without context may it is an out parameter and the sub program writes a result ?

Answer (score 3):

It's writing the dword-sized value 0 (which may be an integer or a NULL pointer on x86) to the dword-sized field at +0Ah in some `struct`. Nobody can tell you any more than that given three lines of context.

Comment: So, 4 bytes of 00-00-00-00 (zero) writes to eax+0Ah address? I.e. for example eax points to 40h (start of variable in memory) then such:  40 01 C8 00 XX XX XX XX XX XX 00 00 00 00 (4 bytes variable screen_with_height + 6 bytes XX and + then 4 bytes zeros eax+0Ah) Am I right?

Comment: Yes, your interpretation seems correct to me -- although I would note that the variable you're calling `screen_with_height` is apparently not just a single integer variable by itself, but rather, it's the first field in an unknown `struct` in the global data section (the one being written to by the line you asked about).